How you handle performance at pagination when you have to count all rows?
I learned page based pagination and cursor pagination. With both, I need the total count to show more results or not. The problem is I count all rows for each new page, it's bad for performance. Is there a solution where I can bypass it or make it in a fast way?
SELECT 
    wp.id,
    u.id as user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, 
    c.id as company_id, c.company,
    wst.id as wst_id,
    wst.start_time,
    wst.end_time,
    wst.send_start_at,
    wst.send_end_at,
    l.name as location,
    (SELECT COUNT(wp.id) AS total 
     FROM workers_plan wp
     LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = wp.user_id
     WHERE wp.tenant_id = $1 
       AND wst.deleted_by IS NULL 
       AND ($3 OR u.company_id = $2)) AS total 
FROM 
    workers_plan wp
LEFT JOIN 
    users u ON u.id = wp.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
    clients c ON c.id = u.company_id
LEFT JOIN 
    workers_plan wp ON wst.workers_plan_id = wp.id
LEFT JOIN 
    location_orders lo ON lo.id = wp.location_orders_id
LEFT JOIN 
    location l ON l.id = lo.location_id  
WHERE 
    wst.tenant_id = $1 
    AND wst.deleted_by IS NULL 
    AND ($3 OR u.company_id = $2)
GROUP BY 
    wp.id, wst.id, u.id, c.id, l.name
ORDER BY 
    wp.id, wp.created_at 
LIMIT 50

Here you see I have a subquery where I count all rows (total). This executes after every 50 results.

Your query is not valid, the table or table alias wst doesn't exist. All questions about performance start with the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, in plain text, and the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for the query. Also in plain text.

Please read this.

Beside the fact that you query does not do any pagination, there is no need for the total count to know if there are more results or not.

if there are less than limit results, there is no more results.
if there are exactly limit results, you can still show a "load more" that will end up on an empty page. It's up to you if this is acceptable or not.
if not, you can fetch limit + 1 results and display only up to limit. If the last result exists (that would be the 51st in your example), you know there are more results.

